# Finding Nodes Recursively in an XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I figure I am overlooking something simple, but I am having difficulty extracting nodes from an XDocument recursively.

I have XML similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<content>
  <operation></operation>
  <entry>
    <observation>
      <templateId/>
      <code></code>
      <value></value>
      <entryRelationship>
        <observation>
          <templateId/>
          <code></code>
          <value></value>
        </observation>
      </entryRelationship>
      <entryRelationship>
        <observation>
          <templateId/>
          <code></code>
          <value></value>
        </observation>
      </entryRelationship>
    </observation>
  </entry>
</content>
```

I thought I could get all three observation nodes using

```
foreach (XElement element in Content.Descendants("observation"))
    ExamineObservation(element);
```

Although it looks like this only works when observation does not have children. I also tried .Ancestors and .DecentantNodes, but didn't get what I wanted.

I can easily write a recursive method that gets me what I need, but I would rather use an existing method if there is one, especially since I will be working with XML quite a bit on several projects. Am I missing something obvious?

Note that any node that says observation, I will need to get the code and value from, so in the example below I will need to process three observation nodes. The nesting and quantity of observation nodes are arbitrary.

Thank you for any assistance.

**ADDENDUM**

It occurs to me that I may not be giving enough information about the XML. I didn't think tags would make a difference, but I suppose I should include them just in case. Below is the first several lines of an actual message I am attempting to parse. I did replace some text with "..." for privacy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<content xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <operation>update</operation>
  <entry xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
      <templateId root="..." />
      <code code="..." codeSystem="..." codeSystemName="..." displayName="...">
      </code>
      <value xsi:type="..." code="..." codeSystem="..." codeSystemName="..." displayName="...">
      </value>
      <entryRelationship typeCode="...">
        <observation classCode="..." moodCode="...">
```

Comment: Sorry I can't catch what is wrong here, if you write `Console.WriteLine(element.Element("code"));` in your foreach you will get three code as expected

Comment: No. I trace through this, and I get nothing back. It completely skips past ExamineObservation(element). The xml is using a namespace; would that make a difference?

Comment: Agreed with xeondev, this should work.  How are you initializing your `Content` node in the foreach loop?

Comment: XDocument Content = XDocument.Parse(message); // Where message is an xml string

Comment: Edited my answer with information about your updated xml with namespace - that's kinda important stuff to know. :)

Comment: Yes, xml namespace does matter, see Gjeltema's answer. And do not forget to use namespace in ExamineObservation method also. like `Console.WriteLine((string)element.Element(nse + "code"));`

Comment: Thank you Gjeltema and xeondev. I bumped each of your comments because my omission screwed up my question. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just ran this code in VS2012, and it hit the `Console.WriteLine()` 3 times, outputting the observation node and contents correctly:

```
        XElement content = XElement.Parse(yourXmlStringWithNamespaceHeader);
        foreach (XElement obs in content.Descendants("observation"))
            Console.WriteLine(obs.ToString());
```

Edit - taking into account the new namespace information, and using `XDocument` instead of `XElement`:

```
        XNamespace nse = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
        XDocument content = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlStringWithNamespaceHeader);
        foreach (XElement ele in content.Descendants(nse + "observation"))
            Console.WriteLine(ele.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry I didn't include that information to begin with. I am learning xml as I go, and this was my first run-in with namespaces. I greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: No worries - sometimes it's hard to whittle down something into an ask-able question, without knowing if it's going to be too little.