# How to work with an XML file that uses namespace

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file that looks like this

```
<j:Registered s:id="SOP_NBR61553">
<RoleOfPerson>
    <PersonBirthDate>
    <Date>1970-08-11</Date>
    </PersonBirthDate>
    <PersonName>
        <PersonGivenName>Joan</PersonGivenName>
        <PersonMiddleName/>
        <PersonSurName>SMITH</PersonSurName>
        <PersonNameSuffixText/>
    </PersonName>
    <sc:PersonRaceCode>W</sc:PersonRaceCode>
    <j:PersonSexCode>F</j:PersonSexCode>
</RoleOfPerson>
<j:RegisteredOffenderIdentification>
</j:Registered>

<se:SopsOffenderAddressList>
<se:SopsOffenderAddress offenderRef="SOP_NBR61553">
    <LocationStreet>
        <StreetFullText>535 ANYWHERE DRIVE</StreetFullText>
        <StreetExtensionText>SOME APARTMENT</StreetExtensionText>
    </LocationStreet>
    <LocationCityName>TALLAHASSEE</LocationCityName>
    <sc:LocationNonFLCounty/>
    <sc:LocationUSStateCode>FL</sc:LocationUSStateCode>
    <LocationPostalCode>32304</LocationPostalCode>
    <LocationPostalExtensionCode>3801</LocationPostalExtensionCode>
    <sc:AddressCategoryCode>TEMP</sc:AddressCategoryCode>
    <se:SOPSAddressIdentification>
        <IdentificationID>644638</IdentificationID>
    </se:SOPSAddressIdentification>
```

I am a Jr. Programmer and have never worked with an XML file.  I can find several examples of parsing a simple XML file but cannot seem to find any good information on drilling down to access the data in child nodes or working with one that uses the namespace.

I tried using this code which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473589/finding-nodes-recursively-in-an-xdocument):

```
string myxml = Convert.ToString(XElement.Load("Sample.xml"));
            XElement content = XElement.Parse(myxml);
            foreach (XElement obs in content.Descendants("Registered"))
                Console.WriteLine(obs.ToString());
```

It compiles and runs but no data is returned to the console.  The end goal is to parse this XML data into a csv file.

Any help to understand how to work with a more complex XML file and get all the data points would be great

I have edited the question and added the top portion of the XML file

```
-<sopde:RegisteredSexOffenderDataExchange xsi:schemaLocation="http://fdle.gov/niem/SexualOffenderPredatorDataExchange/exchange/1.0 file:///C:/Workspaces/MyEclipse/SexPred_Exchange/src/resources/Exchange_Schema.xsd" xmlns:sc="http://fdle.gov/niem/SexualOffenderPredatorDataExchange/extensioncodelist/1.0" xmlns:se="http://fdle.gov/niem/SexualOffenderPredatorDataExchange/extension/1.0" xmlns:sopde="http://fdle.gov/niem/SexualOffenderPredatorDataExchange/exchange/1.0" xmlns:s="http://release.niem.gov/niem/structures/3.0/" xmlns:j="http://release.niem.gov/niem/domains/jxdm/5.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://release.niem.gov/niem/niem-core/3.0/">
```

Thanks
Perry

Well I am making a little progress with this code snippet

```
var FDLE_id = (string) FDLE.Element(j+"RegisteredPerson").Attribute(s+"id").Value;
            var FDLE_BirthDate = (string) FDLE.Element(j+"RegisteredPerson").Element("RoleOfPerson").Element("PersonBirthDate").Element("Date").Value
```

The first line returns the correct data however the next line errors out with this error message {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: I'd recommend you post the top part of your XML; it looks like you posted only the contents of the root element, but the root element is likely where the namespaces are defined.

Comment: That's not the entire XML document. As @Jacob asked, please provide more.

Comment: XElement.Load("Sample.xml") // returns an XElement so you need not convert it to string and then re-parse it to get your XElement.

Comment: Thanks I have taken your advice and am using the XElement.Load command.

Comment: Thanks @spender  I have taken a look at the question you identified as a duplicate of mine and I did get some more helpful information there.  However the XML doc used in that question is still rather simple and does not do a very good job of explaining how to bring in the rest of the data in the other namespaces.  If I could just get an example showing the use of data from 2 separate namespaces I believe I could figure it out from there.  Hopeing someone can provide a good example

Comment: @Jacob I have added the header info to my question.  I hope it is useful in getting some help here

Comment: The linked accepted answer should work for you; just create an XNamespace for each of the `xmlns` declarations in your XML, and access element/attribute names with `ns + "ElementName"`

Comment: Thanks @jacob that is what I am trying to work out now.  Can't seem to get past the first line where there seems to be two xmlns. how can you reference something like <j:Registered s:id="SOP_NBR61553"> both the j: and s: are used in the same tag? Plus it looks like most of the data does not use the namespace

Comment: An XML document can use multiple namespaces.